# Hibernate Associations Criteria All ( Eq, Ne, etc. )

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a very unique query that is giving me some grief in Hibernate. I have the following entities:

```
class Batch {

  private Set exports;
  private boolean locked;

  ...
}

class Export {

  private bool success;

  ...
}
```

I am trying to query for the Batches that are locked and either have no Exports, or only where all the Exports they have done are all false in terms of success. I am able to create criteria to get only Batches that contain at least on Export that is false, but can not seem to find documentation to check that all entities of the join are false. Additionally I was also wanting those that have no Exports previously and found that I can use `setProjection( Projections.rowCount() )`, but that would entail running the query twice. What I have so far is this:

```
Criteria query = session.createCriteria( Batch.class );
query.add( Restrictions.eq( "locked", true ) );
query.createCriteria( "exports" ).add( Restrictions.ne( "success", true ) );
List results = query.list()
```

I'm fairly new to Hibernate and am not completely aware of what can and cannot be done. I would prefer this be done with criteria objects but have no objections to using HQL. If this cannot be done with those can hibernate handle any SQL statement or are there limitations to that as well?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using HQL in your scenario, but I guess following Criteria query would help. May not work exactly but will give you idea.

```
Criteria query = session.createCriteria(Batch.class)
        .createAlias("exports", "exports")
        .add( Restrictions.and(
                Restrictions.eq("locked", true),
                Restrictions.or(
                        Restrictions.isNotEmpty("exports"),
                        Restrictions.ne("success", true)
                        )
                )
```

Comment: It's on the right track though I think I would want isEmpty, not isNoEmpty but that does me no good because the second part of that still returns Batches that have at least one Export where success is not true. Which means it can have others that are true. It's a step in the right direction though, thank you.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry. How about using Subqueries.notExists  
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/criterion/Subqueries.html

Comment: I tried figuring it out, eventually I couldn't even figure out the HQL and had to use a subselect in SQL to make the call.